# Add content if line is not matched

Tags: powershell

Have this script which does lookup. How to change it that it would leave original value if there's no match. Now it leaves blank.

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
$f1 = (Import-Csv 'A.txt' -Delimiter 'µ' -Header samname, id)
$f2 = (Import-Csv 'B.txt' -Delimiter 'µ' -Header samname, id)
$f1 | %{
    $samname = $_.samname
    $m = $f2 | ?{$_.samname -eq $samname}

    $_.id = $m.id
} 
$f1 | Export-Csv 'C.txt' -NoType
```

Input:

`A.txt`:

```
T3-F2-P8629-A1033-L999:µDue Date Calculation
T3-F2-P8629-A1063-L999:µDue Date Calculation
missing
missing
```

`B.txt`:

```
T3-F2-P8629-A1033-L999:µDue Date Calculation
T3-F2-P8629-A1063-L999:µMok. termino skaičiavimas
T3-F8-P8629-A1033-L999:µLast Modified Date Time
T3-F8-P8629-A1063-L999:µLast Modified Date Time
```

Output (`C.txt`):

```
"T3-F2-P8629-A1033-L999:","Due Date Calculation"
"T3-F2-P8629-A1063-L999:","Mok. termino skaičiavimas"
"T3-F8-P8629-A1033-L999:",
"T3-F8-P8629-A1063-L999:",
```

Expected output:

```
"T3-F2-P8629-A1033-L999:","Due Date Calculation"
"T3-F2-P8629-A1063-L999:","Mok. termino skaičiavimas"
"T3-F8-P8629-A1033-L999:","Last Modified Date Time"
"T3-F8-P8629-A1063-L999:","Last Modified Date Time"
```

Comment: Ok figured it out:
     $PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'utf8'
     $f1=(import-csv 'A.txt' -Delimiter 'µ' -header samname,id)
     $f2=(import-csv 'B.txt' -Delimiter 'µ' -header samname,id)
     $f1|
      %{
      $samname=$_.samname
      if ( $m=$f2|?{$_.samname -eq $samname}){
  
       $_.id=$m.id
       } else { $_.id = $_.id}
      } 
      $f1| Export-Csv 'C.txt'  -NoType

Comment: `Import-Csv 'B.txt' -Delimiter 'µ' | Export-Csv 'C.txt' -NoType`